# Sidewaysfigure changing pixel aspect ratio

Tags: pdftex, ghostscript, sidewaysfigure

I'm using `sidewaysfigure` to insert a landscape-oriented full-page map into a 2-column, 8.5x11in pdflatex document. The original image (jpeg, submitted by author with no way to get a proper image format for the map... stuck with jpeg) is 6000x4187 pixels (10in by ~7in at 600dpi, square pixel aspect ratio). Its inserted with:

```
\begin{sidewaysfigure*}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight, keepaspectratio]{image}
\end{sidewaysfigure*}
```

What is odd is that, after compiling, `pdfimages -list` is reporting the ppi as 896x487? The rotated image in the pdf output is degraded form the original.

What's worse is that when I further downsample the pdf with ghostscript (`-sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFSETTINGS=/ebook`), the ppi reports as 215x105 and the mismatched pixel aspect ratio seems to be creating a sort of "tearing" compression artifact in the image, which makes the map's text becomes almost unreadable.

Is this normal behavior? The image's visible aspect ratio doesn't seem to be distorted that I can see, but the image quality is definitely degrading even before downsampling. No way to get a better (preferably `eps`) image from the author, but I need to find a way to make this work.

Comment: it shouldn't be a problem but to get more control don't rotate or scale in latex just include an image as-is, and do any rotation.scaling in a dedicated image system such as gimp or the imagemagic tools or whatever

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'll give that a try. Is it normal for `sidewaysfigure`to change the pixel aspect ratio, or is that a product of the scaling?

Comment: neither sidewaysfigure not \includegraphics has any knowledge of the pixel structure in the image nor any way to change it, it's just handled by the backend of pdftex so something odd is going on but since there is not much control of this at the tex side trying to control it elsewhere might work better

Comment: IIRC, PDF stores images internally in their original form, uncropped and unscaled.  Any changes are effected by the device driver when it is printed or converted to some other format.